# Using Rasp Pi 3 as Plex Home Server, network drive storage

Tags: raspbian, networking, storage

I've just set up a raspberry pi at home as a plex server. I don't want to use external USB storage for the media, ideally I'd like to use a network drive located on a netbook I run on my home network running on Ubunut. I've created a folder on the netbook and shared it with the network using samba, how would I go about mounting this on the raspberry pi and using it as a media storage that the plex server streams from?

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the Samba drive via CIFS using the /etc/fstab config file.
Is more or less explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/313389/196366

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Ans add some like:

```
//192.168.0.5/storage /media/plesk/ cifs guest,uid=myuser,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm 0 0
```

Where:

- //192.168.0.5/storage is the Samba IP and folder
- /media/plesk/ is the local folder you need to create to mount the Samba storage
- uid=myuser is the local user or your Raspberry Pi, maybe "pi"